# Can I make a Django mixin that adds context variables just before template render?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Django application that uses a JSON API as its data source.

Here's a simplified example of use in one of my `views.py`:

```py
class GroupsList(LoginRequiredMixin):
    
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        # Get file list and totals
        try:
            group_list = group_adapter.list() # makes an API call and ALSO populates a meta info class
        except APIAccessForbidden:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('logout'))
    
        return render(request, 'groups/index.html', {
            # can I make a mixin to add data here gained from the API call?
            'group_list': group_list,         
        })
```

This line:

The `group_adapter.list()` call populates some meta information into another class, that's not related to the group_list itself.  I'd like to pass that data to the template.  Ordinarily I'd use a `context_processor`, but when the context processor is called, the API call hasn't been made yet.  I could manually check the information and add it to the `render()` method, but then I'd need to do that in dozens of different views.

### Potential Solution #1: Create a Mixin For It

Can I use a mixin here that adds this information to context **AFTER** the view code runs but **BEFORE** render passes information to the template?

In other words is there a way to do this:

```py
class GroupsList(LoginRequiredMixin, AddMetaInfoToContextMixin):
```

and then create a mixin something like this?

```py
class AddMetaInfoToContextMixin(ContextMixin):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # self.request
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['global_meta_information'] = get_global_meta_information()
        return context
```

### Potential Solution #2: Make an overridden templateview

Commenter Melvyn pointed out that I can potentially subclass TemplateView and override `get_context_data()`, so would something like this work?

```py
class TemplateViewWithMeta(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Home. self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['global_meta_information'] = get_global_meta_information()
        return context

class GroupsList(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateViewWithMeta):
    [...]
```

Comment: I don't get this design. You populate a singleton with meta information when you call the API? Why not return this? And you say this has to be done after the view runs, but before template render, which is contradicting. Either way, any subclass of [`TemplateView`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/) has `get_context_data` which is called before `render_to_response`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You are correct that I am "populating a singleton with meta information" when I call the API.  As for "why not return this", it's because it's information about licensing for the application that needed to be bolted on after the fact.  I'd love to not need to pollute every single view with handling code for it.  It sounds like I can subclass TemplateView and handle this logic in its overridden get_context_data?

Answer (score 1):

The typical workflow for a Django generic TemplateView is:

- get()

  - get_context_data()

    - render_to_response()

So in your case keeping with the spirit of generic views, you could do it like this:

```py
from django.views import generic

class BaseRemoteApiView(generic.TemplateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.group_list = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.group_list = group_adapter.list() # makes an API call and ALSO populates a meta info class
        except APIAccessForbidden:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('logout'))

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class RemoteApiContextMixin(generic.base.ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["group_list"] = self.group_list
        context["meta_information"] = get_global_meta_information()
        return context

class ConcreteRemoteApiView(RemoteApiContextMixin, BaseRemoteApiView):
    pass
```

Of course, you don't have to make 3 classes and can just combine the 3 into one - depends on how mixable you want to be.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to type this out.

Comment: So, all I really need the mixin to do is ADD the global meta info, I don't need it to add the group_list stuff, that I can do in all the individual views.  So I did a `StoreLicenseMixin(ContentMixin)` class and add the global meta to the info, and return context, but I'm not seeing that data in my template.

Comment: I updated my "mixin" proof of concept above.  That's basically what I'm doing and I still don't end up with that data available in the template.

Comment: When is that data created? If it's created in Middleware on the response egress, then the view can never get the information. if it's created out-of-bounds by some other process after the view has been completed - same problem. Rendering is part of the view code, you can't separate it - at least not without changing/bypassing Django's core architecture.

Comment: *"So, all I really need the mixin to do is ADD the global meta info, I don't need it to add the group_list stuff, that I can do in all the individual views."* - Well, you say the meta information is created when you call the API. Secondly you want to logout the user on error, with a redirect. So you are already coupled to the group list and it's not wise to separate it. It's still baffling it doesn't end up in the template, unless you have a typo/error in your template.